# Abuse a certain encounter to prevent Kivan from leaving

Tags: baldurs-gate

I've [read](http://steamcommunity.com/app/228280/discussions/0/558747288163822531/#c558747288227238010) that in order to prevent Kivan from leaving, you may kill and resurrect him. The resurrected character is not supposed to have the quest active and will therefore never leave.

If this is true, can I abuse a certain encounter described below in spoiler text in order to prevent him from leaving?

> The encounter I have in mind is with Shoal the Nereid. If I let Kivan be the victim of her deadly kiss, can I abuse her/it for the purpose described? Sounds almost too good to be true, especially since Shoal is located in a map adjacent to where Kivan is picked up. I did this, but have no idea if it worked. Any way to check (besides wait and see)?

This is a question about BG1 vanilla (not EE, Tutu, etc.).

Comment: From what I see the idea is to kill Kivan and resurrect him after clearing the Bandit Camp. Killing and instantly resurrecting is not guaranteed to work. You could verify that from the console but I have no idea what code you would have to use, probably some of the modders could tell you this. Or perhaps you could use a tool like GateKeeper to figure it out on your own. Anyway, the best solution is to not keep Kivan waiting for too long. He's worth it! :)